# How do you change containers with HTML buttons?

Tags: html, button

So I have this code:

```
<body bgcolor="#FFF"> 
    <table class="body-wrap"> 
        <tr> 
            <td class="container"> 
                <div class="content"> 
                    <div id="logo">
                        <a href="http://www.example.com/"><img src="https://example.com/images/pic.png" /></a>
                    </div> 
                    <form action=""style="text-align:center;">
                    <input type="button" value="News"> <input type="button" value="Twitter"> <input type="button" value="Issues"> <input type="button" value="Info">
                    </form>
                    <td class ="container">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div id="feed"></div> 
                            <a href="http://twitter.com/" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://example.com/images/icon_twitter.png" alt=""> Follow us on Twitter</a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class ="container">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div id="feed"></div> 
                            <a href="http://twitter.com/" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://example.com/images/icon_twitter.png" alt=""> Follow us on Twitter</a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </div> 
            </td>
        </tr> 
    </table> 
</body>
```

And I need a way switch between the two containers that are next to one another by clicking the buttons News and Twitter. (I have intentionally left them identical for this example) Later I will add containers for Issues and Info as well. If anyone knows how to do this I would appreciate it if you would tell me. I'm fairly new to HTML so if you could keep your explanations simple that would help as well. Also I would prefer to keep all the code in one HTML file

Comment: JavaScript. This is very basic stuff. Time to get a book out.

Comment: What do you mean by "switch between containers"?  When someone clicks a button, you want a different container to appear? If so, this isn't going to be achievable with your existing markup without javascript.

Comment: no use table, use normal html `<div></div>`,  `<a></a>`, `<input />`

Comment: Because you're new to HTML here's a quick example of [Tabbed content](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/07/31/creating-content-tabs-with-pure-css/ "Creating Content Tabs with Pure CSS").

Comment: @user3474768 You're welcome, I hope you've achieved what you wanted ;)